# GeoServer WFS-T INSERT Operation in postman using GeoJSON

Tags: geoserver

I am having problems with a POST request to insert features in layers deployed on GeoServer, using GeoJSON. Here is the URL and body of Request created by me and the error I got on sending the request.

URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/poly/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=Transaction&typeNames=poly:Admin2&Content-Type=application/json&Accept=application/json,text/plain
```

Body:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "Admin2.40",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            81.4031982421875,
                            30.4297295750316
                        ],
                        [
                            81.4141845703125,
                            30.467614102257855
                        ],
                        [
                            81.3812255859375,
                            30.519681272749402
                        ],
                        [
                            81.4141845703125,
                            30.62845887475364
                        ],
                        [
                            81.49658203125,
                            30.670990790779168
                        ],
                        [
                            81.54602050781249,
                            30.770159115784214
                        ],
                        [
                            81.6998291015625,
                            30.869225348040825
                        ],
                        [
                            81.7987060546875,
                            30.94463573937753
                        ],
                        [
                            81.88110351562499,
                            30.982318643027536
                        ],
                        [
                            81.88110351562499,
                            31.147006308556566
                        ],
                        [
                            81.837158203125,
                            31.17050982470345
                        ],
                        [
                            81.485595703125,
                            31.236288641793006
                        ],
                        [
                            81.112060546875,
                            31.25037814985571
                        ],
                        [
                            81.00769042968749,
                            31.22219703210317
                        ],
                        [
                            80.4638671875,
                            31.081165464590594
                        ],
                        [
                            80.3155517578125,
                            30.977609093348686
                        ],
                        [
                            80.2166748046875,
                            30.850363469502362
                        ],
                        [
                            80.255126953125,
                            30.741835717889792
                        ],
                        [
                            80.22216796875,
                            30.69933500437198
                        ],
                        [
                            80.22216796875,
                            30.661540870820918
                        ],
                        [
                            80.2166748046875,
                            30.590637026892917
                        ],
                        [
                            80.26611328125,
                            30.590637026892917
                        ],
                        [
                            80.321044921875,
                            30.552800413453546
                        ],
                        [
                            80.386962890625,
                            30.529145036680408
                        ],
                        [
                            80.4803466796875,
                            30.496017831341284
                        ],
                        [
                            80.5462646484375,
                            30.44867367928756
                        ],
                        [
                            80.57922363281249,
                            30.48181700282728
                        ],
                        [
                            80.68359375,
                            30.424992973925598
                        ],
                        [
                            80.760498046875,
                            30.38709188778112
                        ],
                        [
                            80.79345703125,
                            30.344435586368462
                        ],
                        [
                            80.8428955078125,
                            30.32547125932808
                        ],
                        [
                            80.88134765625,
                            30.315987718557867
                        ],
                        [
                            80.947265625,
                            30.278044377800153
                        ],
                        [
                            80.9967041015625,
                            30.278044377800153
                        ],
                        [
                            81.06262207031249,
                            30.197366063272245
                        ],
                        [
                            81.10107421874999,
                            30.111869849235244
                        ],
                        [
                            81.1285400390625,
                            30.050076521698735
                        ],
                        [
                            81.1669921875,
                            30.007273923504556
                        ],
                        [
                            81.23291015625,
                            30.035811042667792
                        ],
                        [
                            81.27685546875,
                            30.088107753367257
                        ],
                        [
                            81.243896484375,
                            30.140376821599734
                        ],
                        [
                            81.2933349609375,
                            30.164126343161097
                        ],
                        [
                            81.331787109375,
                            30.183121842195515
                        ],
                        [
                            81.375732421875,
                            30.20211367909724
                        ],
                        [
                            81.38671875,
                            30.259067203213018
                        ],
                        [
                            81.4031982421875,
                            30.29701788337205
                        ],
                        [
                            81.3922119140625,
                            30.334953881988564
                        ],
                        [
                            81.4031982421875,
                            30.363396239603716
                        ],
                        [
                            81.40869140625,
                            30.39656853856939
                        ],
                        [
                            81.4031982421875,
                            30.4297295750316
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "the_geom",
            "properties": {
                "ST_NM": "KP"
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalFeatures": 40,
    "numberMatched": 40,
    "numberReturned": 3,
    "timeStamp": "2019-12-05T04:59:03.494Z",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
    <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
        <ows:ExceptionText>org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1) 
only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1) </ows:ExceptionText>
    </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do transactions using json only XML. What makes you think this will work?

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/geofence-server/rest-adminrule.html      on this link of geoserver documentation it is written that  "Both XML and JSON are supported for transfer of data objects."

Comment: that link is to the REST api of GeoFence and has nothing to do with WFS-T

Comment: ok, But as the it is possible to GET Features in GeoJSON format, can't it be possible to send POST request in GeoJSON

Comment: You can GET features as zipped shapefiles as well but you can't do WFS-T with them. For json transactions I believe you must wait until they are defined in the OGC API Features standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoServer WFS Transactions can only be built using GML.
You can wait for the new [OGC Features API](https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-features), a future transaction extensions (yet to be written) will likely allow insertion by means of a GeoJSON payload.

In the meantime, you should be able to import GeoJSON files into GeoServer by using the [importer extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/importer/index.html)